# How to prevent default redirection on links that have items

Tags: jquery, html

I have a menu with two drop down. When I click on the first list item that has a drop-down for the first, I can see the sub-items, if I click for the second time, it directs me to its link. How can I do the same for the sub-items of this menu item?

This is how my jquery looks like at the moment.

```
$('ul#main-nav > li.menu-item-has-children').click(function(e) {
    if ($(window).width() < 768) {       
        if (!$(e.target).closest('ul').is('.sub-menu')) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (!$(this).hasClass('important')) {
                $(this).addClass('important');
                //toggle the menu 
            } else {
                //redirect if second click 
                window.location = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

My html structure is like this :

```
<ul id="main-nav">
    <li>
      <a href="/services"></a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li>
              <a href="/condition"></a>
              <ul class="sub-menu">
                  <li><a href=""></a></li>
              </ul>
          </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How can I make it work for the sub items of sub items ?

Unfortunately am not allowed to post the site url.
Hope you can help.

Answer (score 0):

Add in the event handler last line:

```
return false;
```